# ManagedBean inherits another MB. How to reuse the main class JSF as a component?

Tags: jsf, facelets, managed-bean, uiinclude

My problem is a little bit complex, but I'll give an example.

I already have a user.xhtml page (and a MB that uses it) where I register an user

```
<p:outputLabel value="Name:" /> <h:outputText value="#{userMB.bean.name}" />
<p:outputLabel value="e-mail:" /> <h:outputText value="#{userMB.bean.email}" />
etc...
```

Now I create an `UserAdmMB` that inherits `UserMB`, with another fields. I want to reuse the XHTML that exists, like using `<ui:include>`:

```
<ui:include src="user.xhtml" />
<p:outputLabel value="Address:" />
<h:outputText value="#{userAdmMB.anotherbean.address}" />
```

But the first XHTML already has `userMB` in it (to be used in another access point). How is the better way to do that?

Comment: Please step back and reconsider the design all over again from scratch.

Comment: @Tiny: Apart from the awkward "MB" in bean name, this doesn't seem unreasonable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refactor the bean as `<ui:param>` of `<ui:include>`.

The new include:

```
<p:outputLabel value="Name:" /> <h:outputText value="#{user.name}" />
<p:outputLabel value="Email:" /> <h:outputText value="#{user.email}" />
...
```

The clients:

```
<ui:include src="user.xhtml">
    <ui:param name="user" value="#{someBean.user}" />
</ui:include>
```

```html
<ui:include src="user.xhtml">
    <ui:param name="user" value="#{someAdminBean.user}" />
</ui:include>
```